# name of sloccount package on EC2 instance running CentOs Options

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on EC2: I use for that the standard Amazon AMI
based on CentOs

I would like to setup the SLOCCOUNT plugin the same way it runs on my
dev machine (running Ubuntu) but I can't find the package in the
Amazon AWS package repository (sloccount* brings no answer)

Does anyone know if SLOCCOUNT is in the AWS repository and its name ?

Thanks in advance

didier

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the AWS repository but I've had luck getting the rpm from the fedora repos.

```
wget http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/s/sloccount-2.26-12.fc17.x86_64.rpm
```

worked for me.